# Running a for loop in r over columns to calculate mean

Tags: r, for-loop, data.table

I have data with different sequences stored in columns and different treatments. I want to run a for loop over the columns to calculate the mean for the combination of treatment and sequence for the measured values.
This is what I tried

```
library(data.table)

ID<-c(1:10)
Value<-c(60:69)
Treat<-c("X","Y","X","X","Y","Y","X","Y","Y","X")
ABAB<-c(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
BBAA<-c(0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1)
ABCA<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1)

dt<-data.table(ID,Treat,Value,ABAB,BBAA,ABCA)

for(ii in unique(colnames(dt[,3:ncol(dt)])) ){
  dt[ii!=0,mean_value:=mean(Value),by=c(ii,"Treat")]
  dt[ii!=0,sequence:=ii]
 }
```

Because I got rows with multiple sequence I would like to get a result with 2 columns one showing the sequence and the other showing the mean. The approach works outside of the for loop but things get messed up within.

I would be thankful for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the data in long format and calculate average for each `Treat` and each column.

```
library(data.table)

dt_long <- melt(dt, id.vars = c('ID', 'Treat', 'Value'))
dt_long[value != 0, .(Value = mean(Value)), .(Treat, variable)]

#   Treat variable Value
#1:     X     ABAB  61.0
#2:     Y     ABAB  61.0
#3:     X     BBAA  66.0
#4:     Y     BBAA  64.5
#5:     X     ABCA  67.5
#6:     Y     ABCA  67.5
```

The same can be done with `tidyverse` using -

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dt %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -(1:3)) %>%
  filter(value != 0) %>%
  group_by(Treat, name) %>%
  summarise(value = mean(Value), .groups = 'drop')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
    gather(variable, Value, -(1:3)) %>%
    filter(value != 0) %>%
    group_by(Treat, name) %>%
  summarise(value = mean(Value), .groups = 'drop')
```